# Modifing SQL statement to append a column from a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have two tables: `TrainingMatrix` and `Data`. For `TrainingMatrix` I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute") *
            FROM   "TrainingMatrix" 
            ORDER  BY payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute" ,"TrainingDate" DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Each payroll No. is related to a unique employee name. So, in `Data` table I have two columns: `payroll` and `"EmployeeName"`. How can I modify the previous statement such that I can show/project `"EmployeeName"` with the result as well.

I use PostgreSQL 9.2 and pgAdmin III.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your query with the `Data` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("TrainingMatrix".payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute") "Data".EmployeeName, "TrainingMatrix".*
FROM "TrainingMatrix" 
JOIN "Data" ON "TrainingMatrix".payroll = "Data".payroll
ORDER  BY payroll, "TrainingName", "Institute" ,"TrainingDate" DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: thanks dear, you meant `Data` NOT `Fata` :). One more thing how could I put `EmployeeName` as a first column shown ?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, @Aan. I've fixed my answer to address your correction and additional question.